# Apache2 Permission denied: access to / denied

Tags: apache-2.2

after installing and starting apache2 i can't open the website and got the error "***Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.***" I tried some different options in the httpd.conf, but nothing helped me solving this problem.

All permissions for every directory are "drwxr-xr-x".
The directory /var/www contains a file names index.html with the same permissions.
Please do not wonder, the time in the errorlog is not correctly.
I have no idea what the problem is, i hope someone can help me.

**my httpd.conf:**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
Listen 80
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    User daemon
    Group daemon
</IfModule>
    ServerAdmin you@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
ErrorLog /var/apache2/logs/error_log

LogLevel warn


<Directory "/usr/share/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/apache2/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
```

**my error_log:**

```
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:26 2000] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:33 2000] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:34 2000] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:36 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:37 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:37 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:37 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:38 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
[Sat Jan 01 00:50:38 2000] [error] [client 192.168.1.44] (13)Permission denied: access to / denied
```

Comment: Did any of these answers help?

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: i tried it with follow lines:

Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from All

but this have no effect. Do you mean it works, if i remove it completly? I will try it

Comment: His Apache config is not the problem. I tested that config on a VM and it works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the physical filesystem to ensure that /var and /var/www have permissions open enough for the apache user to read/access files?

```
$ ls -ld /var /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. 23 root root 4096 Jun 27  2010 /var
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root root 4096 Oct 27 07:29 /var/www
```

Make sure that's kosher.

Comment: I went and replicated his Apache configs in a spare VM. From what I can tell, his configs are fine, so this very likely points to permissions.